# Merge Columns with the Same name in the same dataframe if null

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
    Depth   DT  DT  DT  GR  GR  GR

1   100    NaN  45  NaN 100 50  NaN

2   200    NaN  45  NaN 100 50  NaN

3   300    NaN  45  NaN 100 50  NaN

4   400    NaN  Nan 50  100 50  NaN

5   500    NaN  Nan 50  100 50  NaN
```

I need to merge the same name columns into one if there are null values and keep the first occurrence of the column if other columns are not null.
In the end the data frame should look like

```
Depth   DT  GR

1   100 45  100

2   200 45  100

3   300 45  100

4   400 50  100

5   500 50  100
```

I am beginner in pandas. I tried but wasn't successful. I tried drop duplicate but it couldn't do the what I wanted. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can do:

```
(df.set_index('Depth')
   .groupby(level=0, axis=1).first()
   .reset_index())
```

output:

```
   Depth    DT     GR
0    100  45.0  100.0
1    200  45.0  100.0
2    300  45.0  100.0
3    400  50.0  100.0
4    500  50.0  100.0
```

Comment: Quang thanks for the reply. Sorry I forgot to frame the question correctly, I have corrected the question now. The column needs to be merged if it is empty. Thanks

Comment: Did you try my code with your new data? Did it not give you what you need?